# How many sets can we create?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

If a set is defined based on the following three points:

$1)$ It has exactly three elements;

$2)$ All elements are in Arithmetic Progression;

$3)$ All elements are primes.

Eg: $ \{3,5,7\}$.

How many such sets are possible?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott would not all sexy prime triplets count for this?  The smallest need not be three.  E.g. (367,373,379) and (607,613,619).  I have not heard a proof or disproof yet on whether infinitely many sexy prime triplets exist, but I would expect given the relaxation that the difference need not be six would allow for infinitely many such triples to exist.

Comment: @JMoravitz: You’re right, of course: I was unconsciously conflating this with another question from long ago that placed limitations on the constant difference.

Comment: As an aside, the largest sexy prime triplet to have been discovered has over 5000 digits.  As a further aside, to those unfamiliar with the term, a triplet is called a sexy prime triplet if of the form $(n,n+6,n+12)$ with all of $n,n+6$ and $n+12$ prime and $n+18$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Green-Tao Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem), for every natural number $k$, there exist arithmetic progressions of primes with $k$ terms.

As an easy corollary to this, there are infinitely many triples $(p,q,r)$ where $p,q,r$ are all prime and in arithmetic progression.